# Configure nginx-ingress to forward bytes to underlying HTTP service, as they arrive

Tags: node.js, nginx, kubernetes, streaming, nginx-ingress

I'm building an API than enable users to stream (push) large content through HTTP and I would like to be able to process the request from a nodejs express server **while the client is still pushing**.

*client.js*

```js
const request = require('request');
someReadableStream.pipe(request({
    method: "POST",
    uri: `${process.env.SERVER_URL || "https://streaming.service.com/"}/`,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_TOKEN}`,
    },
}));
```

*server.js*

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.post('/', function rootPostHandler(req, res) {
  console.log('request received');
  const tickInterval = setInterval(() => console.log('tick'), 1000);
  req.on('data', (chunk) => console.log('data received'));
  req.on('end', () => {
    console.log('request end received');
    clearInterval(tickInterval);
    res.end('done')
  });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Everything works as expected on my development server: server receives data and can start processing it while client is still pushing (see per-second `tick`s in output below).

*dev server output:*

```
request received
data received
data received
data received
tick
data received
data received
data received
tick
data received
data received
data received
tick
data received
data received
request end received
```

Now, when we deploy the same server code to our kubernetes cluster, initial experiments suggest that [Nginx Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) (or some other K8s component) wait the request to be completed before sending it to the underlying HTTP service (no `tick` in output below).

*server pod logs*

```
request received
data received
data received
data received
data received
data received
data received
data received
data received
data received
data received
data received
request end received
```

*kubernetes config*

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  labels:
    tier: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "issuer"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 30720m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "180"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "180"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "180"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - streaming.service.com
      secretName: streaming-tls
  rules:
    - host: streaming.service.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: streaming
                port:
                  number: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: streaming
  labels:
    app: streaming
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    app: streaming
```

**Question:** Is here a way to tell nginx-ingress to forward bytes to underlying HTTP service as they arrive, through [annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/) or [snippets](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-snippets/) for example ?

Answer (score 4):

**Answering to my own question** since it may help others

All you have to do is to add `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-request-buffering: "off"` annotation

*New Ingress configuration*

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-stream
  labels:
    name: ingress-stream
    tier: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-request-buffering: "off"  # here
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: streaming.service.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: streaming
                port:
                  number: 80
```